# Flutter bottom navigation margin not showing when adding FAB

Tags: flutter, material-design, flutter-layout

I was following [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17555) thread in Github to solve my case but didn't fix it.

I am trying to show some margin on the `BottomNavBar` when I add a `FloatinActionButton` in the `Scaffold` but the FAB just overlaps and the margin does not appear.

**What I want:**

[image]

**What I have:**

[image]

**The code:**

```
Scaffold(
        extendBody: true,
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        body: _children[_currentIndex],
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Icon(Icons.search),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          color: Colors.orange,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.movie),
                tooltip: "Text",
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                tooltip: "Text",
              )
            ],
          ),
        ))
```

Notice that I did try with both `BottomAppBar` and `BottomNavigationBar`. What worked was using a `Stack` but I was looking for a more elegant way since [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tsMk2m3H64Y) magically achieves it.
I have the latest version of Flutter.

*Note: Ignore the colors and the icons, just need to see what I'm not doint/I'm doing wrong.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a BottomAppBarTheme to your apps Theme and give it a shape:

```dart
return MaterialApp(
    title: 'Flutter Demo',
    theme: ThemeData(
      // This is the theme of your application.
      //
      // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
      // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
      // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
      // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
      // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
      // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
      // is not restarted.
      primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      bottomAppBarTheme: BottomAppBarTheme(
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
      ),
    ),
    home: MyHomePage(),
);
```

*Edit: expanded the snippet to clarify where to add the `BottomAppBarTheme`*

Answer (score 1):

The BottomAppBar class has two properties of interest: shape, and notchedMargin ([See flutter docs for all properties](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomAppBar-class.html))

You can use the "shape" property to tell the bar to wrap around the FAB. The "notchedMargin" property takes a double and will define the margin if you want a different gap around the FAB.

You don't need to specify the margin if you don't want to change it's default.

Try:

```
Scaffold(
    extendBody: true,
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
    body: _children[_currentIndex],
    floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Icon(Icons.search),
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
    ),
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
      color: Colors.orange,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.movie),
            tooltip: "Text",
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            tooltip: "Text",
          )
        ],
      ),
      shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
    ))
```

[Example screenshot of above shape property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eVPx.png)

Comment: Thanks :) But if you don't want to use a Theme (_not sure why you wouldn't_) to apply this at least there is an alternative in my answer ;)